# Access partial in Module.php

Tags: php, zend-framework2, partials

I got two modules.

1. Application
2. User

Layout is set in Application module, in the layout there are module specific navigation elements that i need to display, here is what i am trying to do.

This is the partial i am calling in **layout/layout** of Application module.

```
//file: module/Application/view/layout/container/layout.phtml
<?php echo $this->partial('toolbar'); ?>
```

This is my **toolbar.phtml**

```
//file: module/Application/view/layout/chunks/toolbar.phtml
<div class="new-top-menu">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand sidebar-toggle-box" href="#">
            <div class="sidebar-left-trigger">
                <span class="fa fa-align-right"></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <?php echo $this->placeholder('notification/top-menu'); ?>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <?php echo $this->placeholder('toolbar/search'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->placeholder('toolbar/right-position1')->set($this->position1); ?>
        <?php echo $this->placeholder('toolbar/right-position2')->set($this->position2); ?>
        <?php echo $this->placeholder('toolbar/right-position3')->set($this->position3); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Basically i want to read another partial named `toolbar/user-menu.phtml` from User module and set it as content of this placeholder `$this->placeholder('toolbar/right-position3');`

I tried doing this in Module.php of User module.

```
namespace User;

public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
    $viewModel->setVariable('position1', 'test string');
}
```

This works absolutely fine, the problem is i want to replace the content 'test string' with the content from partial which is located in `file: module/User/view/toolbar/user-menu.phtml`

Any pointers on how this can be done in ZF2 are appreciated.

Thanks.

### Update1:

I was able to do this using the following code, i am looking forward to if this can be improved, anyhow.

In User/Module.php i updated with the following.

```
use Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer;
use Zend\View\Resolver;

public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $application = $event->getApplication();
    $eventManager = $application->getEventManager();
    $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
    //create a Template Stack
    $stack = new Resolver\TemplatePathStack(array('script_paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/view/user/toolbar')));

    //create a Resolver
    $resolver = new Resolver\AggregateResolver();
    $resolver->attach($stack);

    //create a Renderer
    $renderer = new PhpRenderer();
    $renderer->setResolver($resolver);

    $viewHelperManager = $serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager');
    $urlViewHelper = $viewHelperManager->get('url');

    $partial = $renderer->partial('user-menu', array(
        'signOutUrl' => $urlViewHelper('user-account-sign-out')
    ));
    $viewModel = $event->getViewModel();
    $viewModel->setVariable('position1', $partial);
}
```

That's it, i am able to place the HTML content in the placeholder now, the only issue i am facing now is to access view helper within the user-menu.phtml file, i am currently generating it in Module.php and passing it to the view file.

Comment: Why don't you create a class and define it as a member, so you can reuse it?

Comment: And how is it going to help in my scenario? i was thinking placeholder is a good fit for what i want to do, i am not sure how this can be achieved using independent class.

Comment: I kind of solved the problem, but seems way too messy, ill post the code in here.

Comment: You can define static members. You set the member value and use it whenever you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, because you're starting to look at the native view helpers, but you should not be manipulating those in Module directly, and you should not be trying to change compose the toolbar in your view scripts.

Instead, make your own Toolbar view helper, inject the dependencies via its factory (including the partial template), and then you can simply `echo $this->toolbar()` in your layout view script.

Also, you might take a look at Spiffy Navigation, if nothing else, just for how the view helper is implemented. https://github.com/spiffyjr/spiffy-navigation

Comment: I am not sure how implementing a view helper would he me in my scenario, thank you for your response :)

Comment: It would help because then you can contain all your assembly logic in that class, and inject your dependencies. Right now you're having to put logic in the view script, because you are limiting yourself to the Partial view helper. If you create your own view helper instead, you can let the templates be templates, and let the view helper do the helping :-)

Comment: Aaah, great explanation, thank you for the direction, time to check with view helpers :)